# PayPal API Reccuring payments - payments every 15 months

Tags: php, api, paypal

How i can create recurring payment, that payments will every 15th month using PP API?
What params i need use?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: [Please read the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) regarding the types of questions that are suitable for StackOverflow. This question is better the be asked of Paypal directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the IPN service to verify payment and, express checkout to kick off a subscription with paypal. The subscription would be held between your customer and paypal. **NOT** you and your customer.

i.e.: Your customer would go through PayPal to cancel the subscription, which would notify you and your script.

http://www.micahcarrick.com/php-paypal-ipn-integration-class.html

a quick google search returned that library.